# Splitting field for $f(x)=(x^2+x+2)(x^2+2x+2)$ over $Z_3[x]$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

> Find the splitting field for $f(x)=(x^2+x+2)(x^2+2x+2)$ over $Z_3[x]$. Write $f(x)$ as a product of linear factors.

This is an exercise from Gallian's *Contemporary Abstract Algebra*.

If $Z_3[x]$ is a typo which should be $Z_3$. Then I can extend it first to $Z_3[x]/(x^2+x+2)$ and then go on.

If it is not a typo, then $f(y)\in Z_3[x][y]$. I don't see any way to find the splitting field of $f(y)$ over $Z_3[x]$. How should I handle this problem?

Comment: I think the book means the first option. The second doesn't make much sense since $Z_3[x]$ is not a field.

Comment: @YoniRozenshein  Ah, I see. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to go on, since the second factor is the first factor with $x$ substituted by $x-1$. And of course, the author means over $\mathbb{F}_3$.